# Flexbox/Bootstrap items with text under image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

I'm trying to achieve this image below using flexbox and bootstrap. Though flex box can be used as a responsive code I still choose to use bootstrap for it. **class="col-xs-3"**

[image]

But here's what I've got so far [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ncsgc3gn/2/)

```css
.services-section {
  background: #414142;
  padding: 20px 50px;
}

.services-section .flex-services {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 300px;
}

.services-section .flex-services div {
  text-align: center;
  background: #676768;
  padding: 5px;
  flex: 1 1;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="services-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-3 flex-services">
      <div>
        <img class="img img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x120" alt="Services Icon">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 flex-services">
      <div>
        <img class="img img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="Services Icon">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 flex-services">
      <div>
        <img class="img img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="Services Icon">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 flex-services">
      <div>
        <img class="img img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/180x180" alt="Services Icon">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please note that the text below image are vertically aligned equally..

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `display: flex` property to `.container` and `align-self: baseline` to `.flex-services` class.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ncsgc3gn/5/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi @Ajay Gutpa, thanks for concern. But seems the content text are not vertically align equally.

Comment: yes! try it now. i fixed it.
it was happening because of the way i made comments `//` instead of `/**/`

Comment: Ow haha I didn't saw it also bru. Thanks, btw please upvote my question as It can helps others facing the same issue. :) cheers